# WPF - What replaces BitmapEffectGroup / BitmapEffectCollection in .Net 4?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, effects

I need to stack effects on runtime created image controls. This is fine with a single effect but how do I stack with BitmapEffectGroup/Collection deprecated and when I need to be able to uniquely modify each control's effect?

I thought of adding the control to a grid with an effect but they are already a member of the same grid.

thx

Comment: From reading more I now realize that a stack panel should suffice also. And since I have a finite set of states for the effects I think having an instance of the effect per control is not the most efficient way to create this.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no replacement for that (neither is there for many of the BitmapEffects).